# Show keypresses and mouse clicks on screen

Tags: windows, gratis, keyboard-listener

I am looking for a tool that shows keypresses and mouse clicks.

My requirements:

- [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) also for commercial use
- [windows](/questions/tagged/windows)
- Show keypresses
- Show mouse clicks (LMB, RMB)
- Configurable position and size
- Multi-Screen support
- Shows multiple keypresses for a configurable time ("recent key list")

In contrast to some software I already tried, I need:

- Invisible keys like <kbd>Shift</kbd> should show up immediately after being pressed. Some software only shows them after pressing a regular key (Like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. If I let the invisible key go without pressing a regular button, I want it to disappear immediately and not show up in a recent keypress list
- Invisible keys like <kbd>Shift</kbd> shall be combined with mouse clicks and then stay in the recent key list
- I don't want keypresses be written as `s x2` when I press <kbd>S</kbd> 2 times. It is ok to have such a number with the 4th keypress. It must be clear that I have not typed <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>, so it must e.g. be written in a different color or different font.
- Displays the <kbd>Space</kbd> key well, e.g. as `˽`

I have tried:

- [Carnac the magnicifent](http://carnackeys.com/), but it does not show mouse events and writes `s x2` which is an ambiguous representation.
- [KeyPosé](https://github.com/AxDSan/KeyPose) does not show mouse clicks and just shows a single key in the recent key list. It does replace space by `˽`, but not when in combination with an invisible key.
- [PointerFocus](http://www.pointerfocus.com/) is not [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis)
- [QiPress](http://aalapshah.in/qipress) is not [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis)